# Azure SQL table size grows inconcistently with number of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have a Azure SQL table to which I am writing data from Stream Analytics lets say 1-2 records per minute. The DDL for the table (generated from the table via DBeaver) is

```sql
CREATE TABLE conf.SensorData (
    SensorId varchar(20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    MessageType varchar(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    DataType varchar(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    SeqNumber int NULL,
    DataValue varchar(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    UnixTime int NOT NULL
) GO
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX SensorDataBak_UnixTime_IDX ON conf.SensorData (  UnixTime ASC  , SensorId ASC  )  
     WITH (  PAD_INDEX = OFF ,FILLFACTOR = 80   ,SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF , STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON , ONLINE = OFF , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON  )
     ON [PRIMARY ]  GO;
```

I have 60k records in the table. And the table takes up **7GB**. When I create it again and `INSERT` all the data it takes up only around **8MB**. And after inserting data for a day from the Stream Analytics it takes up again **190MB**.

I just found out, that by running query

```sql
SELECT a.object_id, object_name(a.object_id) AS TableName,
    a.index_id, name AS IndedxName, avg_fragmentation_in_percent
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats
    (DB_ID (N'sqldb-mrs-manage-service')
        , OBJECT_ID(N'conf.SensorData')
        , NULL
        , NULL
        , NULL) AS a
INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS b
    ON a.object_id = b.object_id
    AND a.index_id = b.index_id;
GO
```

suggested by [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/reorganize-and-rebuild-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15#to-check-the-fragmentation-of-a-rowstore-index-using-), I get some heavily fragmented unnamed index in the table:

| object_id | TableName | index_id | IndexdxName | avg_fragmentation_in_percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 203147769 | SensorData | 0 | [NULL] | 99.509 |
| 203147769 | SensorData | 2 | SensorDataBak_UnixTime_IDX | 0 |

Why is this index created and can I drop it Somehow? Or is the growth of the table in size some other issue?

I think the issue may be related to SO question [sql-table-growing-inconsistently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960692/sql-table-growing-inconsistently), but the solution suggested there is installing new Service Pack from 7 years ago.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You don't have a Clustered index on your table, thus your table is in a "heap"; that is what that index is with the ID of `0`.

Comment: So the index `SensorDataBak_UnixTime_IDX` should be without the `NONCLUSTERED` keyword?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/186572/3690

Comment: Removing `NONCLUSTERED` wouldn't make it `CLUSTERED`; an `INDEX` is `NONCLUSTERED` unless specified otherwise. If you want to `INDEX` to be `CLUSTERED` not `NONCLUSTERED` you would need to specify it to be `CLUSTERED`. Though you should endeavour to ensure that the the index canditate is always ascending for a `CLUSTERED INDEX`.

Comment: `FILLFACTOR = 80` is also almost certainly not what you want. Unless you really know what this option does and you are in a position to measure the impact of deviating from the default, just leave it out and go with the default fill factor of 100.

Comment: OK, I've created the table with the index `CLUSTERED` and without specifying the `FILLFACTOR`, so I will see in few hours how it behaves.

Comment: For large data collection in SQL, you might want to consider using a columnstore index instead.  It will compress groups of rows every so often and save space.  You can think of it almost like an auto-partitioning mechanism as well.  Some of the heap code paths can lead to one row per page --> uses more space to avoid contention, which could perhaps explain what you said in your original post.

Answer (score 0):

1. As @Larnu mationed, you may try to remove NonCLustered index  and then put a Clustered index on it. Clustered indexes sort and store the data rows in the table or view based on their key values but NonCLustered can not. As we know Clustered index will affect data storage.
2. You can also consider about [columnstore indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-ver15#what-is-a-columnstore-index) to compress the data storage space further. As we know rowstore indexes perform best on queries that seek into the data, when searching for a particular value, or for queries on a small range of values.
   As @Conor Cunningham MSFT mationed, for large data collection in SQL, we also can combine columnstore-indexes and rowstore columnstore on the same table in Azure sql.